Local Discovery Protocol v4
The following is a minimal implementation of syncthing's Local Discovery Protocol.
I am looking for feedback on:

Improving the efficiency and reliability of the code.
Best practices for this kind of network protocol implementation.
Recommendations for alternative/better designs that could support a wider system.

use prost::Message;

use crate::messages::{Announce, MAGIC_NUMBER};
use std::{
    io::Result,
    net::{SocketAddr, UdpSocket},
    sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver, Sender},
    thread,
    time::Duration,
    vec,
};

const BROADCAST_ADDR: &str = "255.255.255.255:21027";
const SOCKET_ADDR: &str = "0.0.0.0:21027";
const BROADCAST_INTERVAL: Duration = Duration::from_secs(3);

fn receive_announcements(
    instance_id: i64,
    socket: UdpSocket,
    sender: Sender<Announce>,
) -> Result<()> {
    loop {
        let mut buf = [0; 100];
        let (amt, _) = socket.recv_from(&mut buf)?;
        println!("{amt}");

        if let Ok(magic_needle) = <[u8; 4]>::try_from(&buf[0..4]) {
            let magic = u32::from_be_bytes(magic_needle);

            if magic != MAGIC_NUMBER {
                continue;
            }

            let announce = Announce::decode(&buf[4..amt])?;

            if announce.instance_id != instance_id {
                let _ = sender.send(announce);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn send_announcements(instance_id: i64, socket: UdpSocket) -> Result<()> {
    let source = socket.local_addr()?.ip();
    let addr = SocketAddr::new(source, 22000).to_string();

    let announce_message = Announce {
        id: vec![0, 1],
        addresses: vec![addr],
        instance_id,
    };

    let broadcast_socket = socket.try_clone()?;

    let mut message = MAGIC_NUMBER.to_be_bytes().to_vec();
    let mut encoded_message = announce_message.encode_to_vec();

    message.append(&mut encoded_message);

    loop {
        thread::sleep(BROADCAST_INTERVAL);
        broadcast_socket.send_to(&message, BROADCAST_ADDR)?;
    }
}

pub fn start_discovery(instance_id: i64) -> Result<Receiver<Announce>> {
    let (tx, rx) = channel::<Announce>();
    let socket = UdpSocket::bind(SOCKET_ADDR)?;

    socket.set_broadcast(true)?;

    let recv_socket = socket.try_clone()?;

    thread::spawn(move || send_announcements(instance_id, recv_socket));
    thread::spawn(move || receive_announcements(instance_id, socket, tx));

    Ok(rx)
}


specification
Thank you for mentioning "v4" in the title.
The source code needs to mention that, plus the following URL:
https://docs.syncthing.net/specs/localdisco-v4.html
That is, when claiming to conform to a spec, we must cite the spec.
partial implementation
The OP code ignores the second sentence of the spec:

It also keeps a table of the announcements it has seen.

We need to maintain such a table,
and the Public API needs to somehow make the current table available to callers. It would resemble the rwho command.
dual stack
There are three kinds of protocol participants:

IPv6 (preferred, no NAT needed)
IPv4 (legacy)
dual stack supporting both internet protocols

The OP code only uses IPv4, and so will never hear IPv6 announcements
and will never be heard by hosts of the first kind.
Even when this app is run on a dual stack host.
Minimally the source code should document this deviation from the spec.
It is true that in a testbed which exercises the send and receive routines,
the pair of matched routines will find each other.
But they could have done that with procedure calls.
For a receiver to participate in the protocol means to conform to it,
identifying all conforming senders, even senders on other hosts, even IPv6 senders.
For a sender to participate means to announce to all receivers,
including IPv6 receivers.
Registries aren't handing out /24 allocations anymore, and NAT is no fun.
If you claim spec compliance, you should implement the whole spec.
If you find it necessary to scope down to a subset profile of the spec,
prefer IPv6 as it is the future.
return values
Can we view this as a sensible signature?
What does this even mean?
fn send_announcements( ... ) -> Result<()> {

If I am very very patient, I will obtain a Result?!?
But we loop forever!
Similarly for receive_announcements().
This brings us back to the business of receiver needing
to offer some polling mechanism or push mechanism
for revealing to a calling application the current set of discovered resources.
protocol deviation
This isn't quite a protocol "violation".
const BROADCAST_INTERVAL: Duration = Duration::from_secs(3);


It is recommended that local discovery Announcement packets be sent on a 30 ... second interval

It does warrant a comment in the source code that we're
ignoring the recommendation, together with a comment about
the design rationale for that choice.
The only means of adjusting such parameters is to recompile from source.
Let's just say that if I was a network admin who found such implementations
running wild on my LAN, I would not be amused.
No need to yearn for the good ol' days of chatty protocols like AppleTalk.
You'd be surprised how many similar devices can pop up in a broadcast domain.
The spec, alas, does not touch upon using multicast rather than broadcast,
so there's little we can improve on that front.

Improving the efficiency ... of the code.

OP code works fine.
It's the efficiency of other hosts within the broadcast domain that I'm worried about.
The 10x increased sending rate suggests that "minimizing discovery latency"
prominently appears in some Requirements document.
Yet the spec's advice regarding "immediate transmissions when a previously
unknown device is discovered" has gone unheeded,
without a line of code nor a single comment about the design rationale.

Best practices for this kind of network protocol implementation.

The spec regrettably doesn't mention "jitter your timers!".
But it should.
And send_announcements() should add a little bit of random delay
to each sending interval.
Neglecting to add jitter tends to result in hosts synchronizing,
so we see seconds of silence followed by a back-to-back broadcast burst
from the subset that have synchronized with each other.
I have seen this in production with IMAP clients interacting with a mail server.
The BGP4 protocol spec now enshrines the "jitter!" requirement,
after synchronization led to broad scale WAN outages on the commercial internet.
device ID

The device ID is the SHA-256 (32 bytes) of the device X.509 certificate

I didn't notice an X.509 certificate in the OP code.
It's hard to see how this would correspond to such a SHA-256 digest:
    let announce_message = Announce {
        id: vec![0, 1], ...

The spec explains that you need to be this tall to ride the ride.
If you lack an X.509 cert, you don't get to ride.
debug
Reporting number of bytes received was helpful during initial development.
        println!("{amt}");

Now that we're ready for a Pull Request review prior to merging into main,
it's time to remove such debugs.
Or at least use a proper logger with adjustable verbosity,
and a sufficiently descriptive message that humans a year from now
will be able to correctly interpret the meaning of logs
without recourse to the source code.
interop bake-off
Code that can successfully announce and detect an instance
of itself is necessary, but not sufficient.
The source code or its associated documentation
should detail the product IDs, configs, and version numbers
of other implementations it has interacted with,
and a description of how successful that interaction was.
For example, interacting with a SyncThing implementation
on an IPv6-only host would not go smoothly for the OP code.

Thank you for your feedback. I'm in tears, but I appreciate you taking the time to help me improve. These insights are valuable, and I'll think them over deeply when I'm ready to tackle this again.
